# qtjackctl ./configure returns JACK library not found

Tags: software-installation, jack

Trying to get qtjackctl up and running in just installed 16.04.....

I've installed qt5 and JACK, then:

```
$ cd qjackctl-0.4.3
$ ./configure"
[...]
configure: error: JACK library not found.
```

I've done a fair amount of forum hunting, which I rely on to do anything and everything in Ubuntu.

Comment: Which `jack` package(s) did you install, exactly?

Answer (score 7):

JACK development files are in the `libjack-dev` package. Install it with:

```
sudo apt install libjack-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

The [David](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) answer is correct; but only works with you have installed Jack 1 version. Remember that exist two versions of jack audio server, technically Jack 1 and Jack 2 are equivalent implementations of the same protocol, but... More info about jack's versions [here](https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/Q_difference_jack1_jack2).

Well, if you've installed Jack 2 the development files are in `libjack-jackd2-dev`, so:

```
sudo apt install libjack-jackd2-dev
```

Comment: You're a wizard! Thanks